# Is it true that $\varepsilon u \to 0$ if $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded in $W^{-1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded in $W^{-1,\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\varepsilon >0$.
Is it true that $$\varepsilon u(x) \to 0 \text{ as } \varepsilon \to 0?$$

Comment: I suppose this notation means that $u$ is a bounded functional on $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$? If so, is this not just as simple as $$\| \varepsilon u - 0 \|_{\text{op}} = \varepsilon \|u\|_{\text{op}} \to 0$$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ since $u$ is bounded (and therefore $\|u \|_{\text{op}}$ is finite).

Comment: I do not understand a question. If $u : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is **any** function, you have $\varepsilon u(x) \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ for **all** $x$.